# Enforcing const-correctness when converting lambdas to std::function

Tags: c++, lambda, constants

I have a function that takes in a `std::function` as a parameter. However, I want to ensure the function being passed in is not allowed to modify the parameters passed to it.

Here's the simple version of the function (note that `T` can be, and usually is, a reference):

```
template <class T>
void Bar(std::function<void(std::add_const_t<T>)> func)
{
    // ...
}
```

Bad usage:

```
Bar<int&>([](int&) { /* Do nasty stuff! */ }); /* A-OK! */
```

I want to disallow that usage, but this code compiles perfectly fine, even though I feel like it shouldn't.

Interesting thing is, if I get rid of the template parameter, i.e.:

```
void Bar(std::function<void(const int&)> func)
{
    // ...
}
```

Then, this usage wouldn't compile (as it shouldn't):

```
Bar([](int&) { /* Do nasty stuff! */ }); /* Error C2664 */
```

How can I enforce this and still keep the template parameter?

Comment: Note `std::add_const_t<int&>` is `int&`.

Comment: @aschepler I saw that in the documentation as well. So I even tried doing a hacky version: `const T`, which I thought would deduce to `const int&`. But nope. It still compiles just fine even if I replace `std::add_const_t<T>` with `const T`.

Comment: @Zeenobit: Templates aren't macro's. This is more similar to `typedef int& T; T const ref;` - again `ref` will be `int&`. Compare also to pointers: `typedef int* T; T const ptr` gets you an `int*const` not `int const*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `std::add_const_t<int &>` is `int &`, for you are not adding `const` to `int`. Instead you are adding `const` to a reference to `int` and you obtain a const reference to `int` (that is `int &`), not a reference to a `const int`.

A simple way to work around it can be:

```
#include<functional>
#include<type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct to_const_ { using type = std::add_const_t<T>; };

template<typename T>
struct to_const_<T &> { using type = std::add_const_t<T> &; };

template<typename T>
using to_const_t = typename to_const_<T>::type;

template <class T>
void Bar(std::function<void(to_const_t<T>)> func)
{}

int main() {
    Bar<int&>([](int&) {});
}
```

The code above doesn't compile (as requested), unless you turn it to:

```
Bar<int&>([](const int &) {});
```

Note that it works correctly only with lvalue references as it stands, but adding the support for rvalue references and pointers is straightforward if you got the idea.

---

It follows a minimal, (probably) working example:

```
#include<functional>
#include<type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct to_const_ { using type = std::add_const_t<T>; };

template<typename T>
struct to_const_<T &> { using type = std::add_const_t<T> &; };

template<typename T>
struct to_const_<T &&> { using type = std::add_const_t<T> &&; };

template<typename T>
struct to_const_<T * const> { using type = std::conditional_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value, typename to_const_<T>::type * const, std::add_const_t<typename to_const_<T>::type> * const>; };

template<typename T>
struct to_const_<T *> { using type = std::conditional_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value, typename to_const_<T>::type *, std::add_const_t<typename to_const_<T>::type> *>; };

template<typename T>
using to_const_t = typename to_const_<T>::type;

template <class T>
void Bar(std::function<void(to_const_t<T>)> func)
{}

int main() {
    Bar<int **>([](const int **) {});
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `static_assert` to make compilation fail, with help from templates.

```
//Base case - T is non-const, possibly pointer or reference
template <typename T> struct is_const_param { static constexpr bool value = !std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value && !std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value && !std::is_pointer<T>::value; };

//T is const, but possibly pointer to non-const
template <typename T> struct is_const_param<const T> { static constexpr bool value = !std::is_pointer<T>::value; };

//Remove reference, try again
template <typename T> struct is_const_param<const T&> : is_const_param<const T> {  };

//Remove reference, try again
template <typename T> struct is_const_param<const T&&> : is_const_param<const T> {  };

//Remove pointer, try again
template <typename T> struct is_const_param<const T*> : is_const_param<const T> { };

//Remove pointer, try again
template <typename T> struct is_const_param<const T* const> : is_const_param<const T> { };
```

The `static_assert` would just look like:

```
template <class T>
void Bar(std::function<void(T)>)
{
    static_assert(is_const_param<T>::value, "...");
}
```

This is set up to only succeed when `T` is:

1. Passed by value (see below).
2. Passed by constant reference.
3. Passed by pointer(s) to constant.

You can see some test cases [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f85e12dbceb25fc5) if you want to see examples of what makes it succeed or fail.

---

This was set up to allow passing by value normally, like `Bar<int>`. If you want to change it to only allow `Bar<const int>`, remove the `is_const_param<const T*>` specialization and change the initialization of `value` in the unspecialized template to `false`. You can see that [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67fccece5c964e09).

Comment: What about `T **`?